Running a 12/2 Wire from my house to garage and hanging it over head on a cable
need to run a 12/2 wire from the breaker box in house to garage that is 40 ft away, would like to hang the wire on a cable overhead the yard to garage. Is this allowed by the code ?

I take it this is for 120V only?

You won't be able to use normal NM-B. What wire type are you planning to use? Also are you familiar with the clearances? Check 230.24 to understand those. Most are 10' or higher.

NEC 340.12 allows UF-B cable for this purpose when it is a) labeled for sunlight resistance and b) supported by a messenger cable. That cable must be grounded and there are clearance requirements that depend on location. Clearance is described in 230.24 as per KMJ's comment, and article 396 covers messenger-supported wiring.
